# Vagrant 'pre-boot' VM customization error

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

What is the cause of this particular error?

I have the latest version of VirtualBox (5.2.22-126460) and Vagrant (2.2.2).
Those are running on a freshly installed Windows 10 operating system.

Whenever I try to 'vagrant up' my machine I get this following output:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Vagrant has detected a configuration issue which exposes a
==> default: vulnerability with the installed version of VirtualBox. The
==> default: current guest is configured to use an E1000 NIC type for a
==> default: network adapter which is vulnerable in this version of VirtualBox.
==> default: Ensure the guest is trusted to use this configuration or update
==> default: the NIC type using one of the methods below:
==> default:
==> default:   https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html#default-nic-type
==> default:   https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/networking.html#virtualbox-nic-type
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 1080 (guest) => 1080 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
A customization command failed:

["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected0", "on"]

The following error was experienced:

#<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "22fda01f-9b13-43f9-bf0d-4deb81c688c8", "--cableconnected0", "on"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid NIC number 0
>

Please fix this customization and try again.
```

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "local.1400degrees.com"

    config.vm.hostname = "local.website.com"

    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant",  :mount_options => ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]

    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 1080, host: 1080
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.13"

    config.hostmanager.enabled = true
    config.hostmanager.manage_host = true

    config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
    config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'

    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]
    end
end
```

Comment: That could be a bad Vagrant box based on that error.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/1809) a solution can be to

1.first of all destroy the virtual box with `vagrant destroy`

2.navigate to `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME`

3.delete the `.vagrant.d` folder

4.go into `VirtualBox VMs` folder and delete everything inside it.

5.start it again with `vagrant up`

You can get more in depth logs by using `vagrant up --debug` or if you would like to save it to a file `vagrant up --debug &> vagrant.log`. Also, a great thing about this is you can always tear it down and start over :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the real reason this is happening is due to this: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10481

The fix was already merged to the vagrant master branch, however it will probably be included in version 2.2.5 or later. Latest vagrant version as of writing this up is 2.2.4 and the bug is still present.

The fix that was done:

In plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_default_nic_type.rb

They changed the code from E1000_SUSCEPTIBLE = Gem::Requirement.new("<= 5.2.22").freeze to E1000_SUSCEPTIBLE = Gem::Requirement.new("< 5.2.22").freeze